# Image size reduction from comision art after saving with paint

Tags: image-processing

I comission some art, and have a problem with an artist:

He sends me a finished digital picture with normal size. For example, 5 mb for 4k x 5k resolution.

But once I go to the program "paint" and save the picture there, the size gets reduced to over 1.5 mb.

It only happens with that artist. Does someone know why?

Note: The image with the size reduced is the exact same as the original. There's no quality loss, it's as if it were the exact same.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the image format and compression as received, and the image format and compression as saved in Paint?  Also, how do you know there's no quality loss?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the scope of Arts & Crafts as defined in the [Help Center](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Not an answer, but get Gimp, which is free. It has a lot more options for editing as well as saving. Paint is the minimum to edit images while Gimp is on par with previous versions of Photoshop. Gimp will have the lossless file formats available.

Answer (score 1):

The file he is sending you must be a lossless file or a file that has very little compression. It could also have a higher bit too. The details of the images should be displayed within the exif tags within the photo file. Download an image meta tag / exif reader to get more information on the properties attached to the file. After you save the file and see a smaller size, and the pixel count is the same, your version has a much higher compression. Using in this case, image quality is lost. It may not be noticeable to you because it’s very subtle. Other people using different monitors/color profiles may have a much more noticeable difference.